# Addobject NSMutableArray to a NSDictionary

Tags: iphone, ios, arrays, nsmutablearray, nsdictionary

I am trying to add an `NSMutableArray` to an `NSDictionary` but I get this issue when show `NSDictionary` in log:

```
)' of class '__NSCFArray'.  Note that dictionaries and arrays in
property lists must also contain only property valúes.
```

This is the code I use to create the `NSMutableDictionary`

```
NSMutableDictionary *training = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
[training setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:eltiempo] forKey:@"tiempototal"];
[training setObject:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:totalkm] forKey:@"distanciatotal"];
[training setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:(int)(velocidadmedia/60)] forKey:@"velocidadmedia"];
[training setObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%2d:%02d min/km"] forKey:@"fecha"];
[training setObject:posiciones forKey:@"posiciones"];
```

Where posiciones is the array I want to add. I save this dictionary in an array in order to save it in User Defaults. But as I have this problem the `NSDictionary` is no created.

Thanks for you help.

Pedro

Comment: maybe this is not the problem but i see an invalid string format for the key "fecha".

Comment: You did not paste the entire log message. The problem seems to be that the array or the dictionary contains an objects that is not part of the blessed property list type group (NSString, NSArray, NSDictionary, NSDate, NSData, NSNumber).

Answer (score 0):

you add it to the array just fine ^^ you want to write to a plist (according to the error) and  posiciones contains non-plist types that cannot be used in a plist

Answer (score -5):

Pedro Piñera Buendia,

Try this code,

```
NSMutableDictionary *woRows = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
NSMutableArray *workOrders = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

[woRows  setValue:[workOrders objectAtIndex:0] forKey:@"somekey"];
[woRows setValue:[workOrders objectAtIndex:1] forKey:@"somekey"];
[woRows setValue:[workOrders objectAtIndex:2] forKey:@"somekey"];
```

Comment: -1: No word on what's different from what the poster is already doing. I for one can't see anything (except that your code overwrites the same key three times and will crash, but it's sample code).